# R Mantener la repetición aleatoria en una función de repetición de vector

Tags: r, random, function

Necesito repetir 100 veces un vector de 16 números: este vector tiene algunas posición unos números fijados y otros se generan aleatoriamente. He creado una función para repetir este vector 100 veces, pero simplemente me copia el 1r vector 100 veces, y no me genera nuevos números aleatorios, simplemente copia los aleatorios creados la 1a vez.

```
r1<- c(1,3,2,1,2,sample(1:4,1,replace=T),4,sample(1:4,1,replace=T),3,sample(1:4,1,replace=T),
       sample(1:4,1,replace=T),2,sample(1:4,1,replace=T),1,sample(1:4,1,replace=T),3)
rep.row<-function(x,n){
        matrix(rep(r1,each=100),nrow=100)
}

rp <- rep.row(r1)
```

Como podría obtener 100 vectores, manteniendo la aleatoriedad en los lugares deseados?

Saludos y muchas gracias,

Comment: Hola Marc Vives, no sé si has notado que este sitio es SO en español. Por favor traduce tu pregunta al español o de lo contrario será cerrada.

Comment: Disculpa, me he confundido, ahora lo traduzco

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás repitiendo una misma fila 100 veces, los valores aleatorios no se regeneran. Cambiando el enfoque, se podría hacer esto:

```
# Creo una matriz de 100*16 (dejo en Nan las columnas que van a ser aleatorias)
matrix <- matrix(rep(c(1,3,2,1,2,NaN,4,NaN,3,NaN,NaN,2,NaN,1,NaN,3),each=100),nrow=100)
# Reemplazo las columnas en NaN por valores aleatorios, la muestra es la     cantidada de columnas por filas que se quiere reemplazar
matrix[is.na(matrix)] <- sample(1:4,100*6,replace=T)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos por las soluciones. Disculpad la demora a contestar, he andado muy liado estos días. Saludos,

Answer (score 0):

Una opción sería crear una **función** tal que genere una secuencia aleatoria como la que necesitas y luego utilizar la función **replicate** pare generarla las veces que necesitas:

```r
gen_num <- function() {
  sample(1:4, 1, replace = T)
}

gen_num()
#> [1] 3
gen_num()
#> [1] 4

generar_seq_random <- function() {
  r1 <- c(1, 3, 2, 1, 2, gen_num(), 4, gen_num(), 3, gen_num(), gen_num(), 
    2, gen_num(), 1, gen_num(), 3)
  r1
}

# es una funcion :D
generar_seq_random()
#>  [1] 1 3 2 1 2 3 4 3 3 2 2 2 1 1 4 3

generar_seq_random()
#>  [1] 1 3 2 1 2 3 4 2 3 1 4 2 4 1 3 3

# replicamos la funcion 100 veces
res <- replicate(100, generar_seq_random())

# trasponemos por que la entrega traspuesta
res <- t(res)

# 100 secuencias de largo 16
dim(res)
#> [1] 100  16

head(res)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
#> [1,]    1    3    2    1    2    4    4    4    3     1     2     2     3
#> [2,]    1    3    2    1    2    1    4    2    3     4     4     2     1
#> [3,]    1    3    2    1    2    1    4    2    3     1     3     2     3
#> [4,]    1    3    2    1    2    3    4    1    3     3     1     2     1
#> [5,]    1    3    2    1    2    4    4    1    3     4     3     2     4
#> [6,]    1    3    2    1    2    2    4    1    3     3     3     2     4
#>      [,14] [,15] [,16]
#> [1,]     1     1     3
#> [2,]     1     3     3
#> [3,]     1     4     3
#> [4,]     1     1     3
#> [5,]     1     4     3
#> [6,]     1     1     3
```

Comment: Muchas gracias a ambos por las soluciones. Disculpad la demora a contestar, he andado muy liado estos días. Saludos,